# virtual parallel port connector in QEMU

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, qemu, parallel-port

I have been reading Linux Device Drivers 3rd edition and have been running linux 2.6 in QEMU. However, I am at the point where it requires real hardware. I attempted to emulate a paralleport connector in QEMU with no luck. The host has no parallel port connector.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -parallel file:outputfile  --enable-kvm -smp 2   -initrd initramfs.igz -kernel arch/x86/boot/bzImage -m 1024 -append "console=ttyS0 loglevel=8" -nographic
```

I then wrote a module to access the parallel port connector via `request_region(0x378,1,"parallelport");`. However, whenever I attempt to write to the ioport region, none of the output is seen in the file "outputfile" in the working directory where QEMU was booted. I have also added the `CONFIG_PARPORT` option in the kernel and added some of its associated CONFIG's (i.e CONFIG_PARPORT_PC...) which seemed to only add the linux built-in driver or register an IRQ handler. With this, I was still unable to write to the parallelport "outputfile" on the host machine.

However, I can read and write to the ioport region (meaning whatever I do write with `outb` can be then read with `inb`. However, it is not written to the parallel port `outfile`, which leads me to believe something is still wrong.

I was wondering if I could get some suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong or how to start going about this? The only research I found was the different paralleport options for qemu (use host devices, over udp, etc...), which I tried with no luck. In addition, with using the outputfile option or any option that does not require a host machine parallel port, is it possible to simulate interrupts?

Update: After playing around a little more, it seems the operations of writing and reading from the ioport are working (still don't appear in the outputfile thought). This is because when I do `-parallel none`, I can obtain the ioport and write to it, but reading from it results in unprintable characters (not the ones I inputed). This doesn't happen by default (specifying no `-parallel` option or when `-parallel file:outputfile`.

Update2: From QEMU `-device` documentation I found that `-parallel` is legacy. So I changed my command to the following:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -chardev file,path=./outputfile,id=parallel0 -device isa-parallel,chardev=parallel0,iobase=0x378,irq=7,index=0 --enable-kvm --smp 2   -initrd initramfs.igz -kernel arch/x86/boot/bzImage -m 1024 -append "console=ttyS0 loglevel=8" -nographic
```

and then loaded the driver and made a chardev /dev/parallel0. However, this still didn't work.

Comment: The `path` parameter of the parallel device is your host's path to the device. Also, try removing `-device isa-parallel`.

Comment: Yeah ./outputfile is the file on the host I want the parallel port data on the guest to get directed to. Which the qemu docs said could be just a regular "file". Since the host has no parallel port

Comment: Go to https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html#Character-device-options and search for *parallel*, there it says `*path* specifies the path to the parallel port device`

Comment: Also on the link you posted it specifies : `chardev file ,id=id ,path=path

    Log all traffic received from the guest to a file.

    path specifies the path of the file to be opened. This file will be created if it does not already exist, and overwritten if it does. path is required.` This is also similiar to the first parameters I tried `-parallel file:outputfile`.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to ask on the mailing-list? https://lists.nongnu.org/mailman/listinfo/qemu-discuss

Comment: Have you found the right solution? I'm facing the same issue.